# Unable to execute powershell script. Email is the function name in the script. When I execute the script Getting this error :

Tags: function, powershell

```
        function send_email
             {  
                param([string]$status, [string]$subject, [string]$Mailbody)
    $sysDate=(Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
    $From = "gampa_rajesh@XXX"
    $To = "gampa_rajesh@XXX"
    $Cc = "gampa_rajesh@XXX"
    $MailSubject = $subject+" "+$status+"_"+$sysDate
    $Body = "Hi All,"
    $SMTPServer = "XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

$SMTPPort = "25"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $MailSubject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort
}

Comment: This is the exception I get:      Exception: System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'send_email' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at

Comment: The error message indicates that the script you are executing at the time of the error is trying to call a function or cmdlet named `send_email`. Are you perhaps doing that in a _different_ script that should be trying to call _this_ function `Email` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code. I actually got error on send_email function only. I am calling this function from within the script. I am passing  3 arguments status, subject and body to this send_email function.

Comment: The script is working fine in one of the servers but not working in the server where I want to run this script.

Comment: The error you are reporting indicates that the cmdlet/function `send_email` doesn't exist. Is the script you are calling this from in a different `.ps1` file from this function? If so, you will need to execute this file _before_ your other one, or include the contents of this one _in_ the other one, _before_ the function is called.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am calling this function with in the same script. something like below example: 
if ($status -eq 'COMPLETE')
{  
   send_email $status $subject $emailBody
}

Comment: If the function is defined in the same script that it is being called from, you _must_ have the definition before the call. The error you are getting suggests that this is not the case.

Comment: Jeff Zeitlin - If that is the case then the same script should not work in other servers also. However, it is working in other servers where I initially tried the script. I need to set up the script as scheduler job so need to run the same script in scheduler server.

Comment: @MikeLAngelo offers one possible reason for the difference; you'll need to validate the environments that you're trying to execute this script in.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the other server the function is stored in the powershell profile or dot-sourced somewhere.
Make sure you paste the function text into your PowerShell Session, or otherwise execute it prior to calling it. You can also save the function in a .ps1 file then dot source it. More info on [Microsoft Devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-do-i-use-a-windows-powershell-script-containing-functions/)

Comment: Thank You all for the suggestions. I just placed the function definition on top of the function call and then it worked. It looks like the definition should come first before the call.

Comment: Yes, the function has to be defined (i.e. the function code has to be executed) before the function is called, otherwise it stays undefined.